# "Illegal string offset" error when fetching array for dataTable jquery plugin

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, datatables

I created an ajax json response in which will be displayed in my dataTable jquery plugin. the id of the table is #dataTable.

here is the code for the dataTable plugin:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var productTable = $("#dataTable").DataTable({
        "ajax": "../api/ajax/getProduct.php",
        "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]]
    });
});
```

here is the getProduct.php

```
<?php
include_once('../../components/db.php');

$sqlb = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE status='active'";
$resultb = $conn->query($sqlb);
$data = $resultb->fetch_assoc();

$result = array();

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $image = '<img width="50" height="40" class="rounded-circle" src="../' . $value['image'] . '; ?>">';

    $buttons = '<a href="product-update.php' . $value["id"] . '" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><a onclick="removeProduct(' . $value["id"] . ')" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>';

    $result[$key] = array(
        $value["description"],
        $value["price"],
        $image,
        $value["availability"],
        $buttons,
    );
}// /foreach

echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

here is the error that i've been getting as I check the XHR

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'image' in C:\xampp\htdocs\copy\api\ajax\getProduct.php on line 11

Warning: Illegal string offset 'id' in C:\xampp\htdocs\copy\api\ajax\getProduct.php on line 13

Warning: Illegal string offset 'id' in C:\xampp\htdocs\copy\api\ajax\getProduct.php on line 13

Warning: Illegal string offset 'description' in C:\xampp\htdocs\copy\api\ajax\getProduct.php on line 16

Warning: Illegal string offset 'price' in C:\xampp\htdocs\copy\api\ajax\getProduct.php on line 17

Warning: Illegal string offset 'availability' in C:\xampp\htdocs\copy\api\ajax\getProduct.php on line 19
```

and here's the popup error that i've been getting from the dataTable itself as the page load.

```
DataTables warning: table id=dataTable - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1
```

it seems like the real problem here is the encoded data itself is wrong. with this error, I cannot display the data into the dataTable itself.

Comment: remove the last comma inside the $result array after $buttons, then if that does not fix it instead of echoing $result try to echo test string and see what you get. echo json_encode("test"); Also, on the getProduct.php page, at the top add, header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8"); just before your $include_once(".... and after <?php

Comment: try to `var_dump($data); die();` before the `foreach` and post the result here.

Comment: @Icewine I've tried doing your approach. i;ve added the header as well as added the json_encode("test"). i've test thou output of it using an ajax response and it's not outputting "test" on the console

Comment: @Bluetree https://jsfiddle.net/bzhur8tn/

Comment: remove the json_encode("test") and put the $result back in there but keep the header from before. Then in your code just after $(document).ready(function() { and before var productTable.... add a new ajax request to test what response you are getting. try this: $.ajax({type: "post", url: "../api/ajax/getProduct.php", success: function(data){ console.log("success"); console.log(data); }, error: function(e){console.log("error"); console.log(e);}});

Comment: @Bluetree should be outputting all data within the database

Comment: @LexCabrera Did you test my answer? Base on php documentation https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php  `fetch_assoc()` it just return 1 row.

Answer (score 1):

Base on the `var_dump($data);` result:

```
 array(9) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["names"]=>
  string(12) "Fruity Split"
  ["price"]=>
  string(5) "50.00"
  ["qty"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["image"]=>
  string(26) "images/products/menu-2.jpg"
  ["description"]=>
  string(90) "Dessert made with a split banana, ice cream, sauce, whipped cream, nuts, and a strawberry."
  ["category"]=>
  string(7) "dessert"
  ["availability"]=>
  string(9) "Available"
  ["status"]=>
  string(6) "active"
}
```

The reason why it gives you this error:

> Warning: Illegal string offset

It's because you are just looping  **1 row**.

Instead change your code to this:

```
<?php
include_once('../../components/db.php');

$sqlb = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE status='active'";
$resultb = $conn->query($sqlb);

// This just return single row
// $data = $resultb->fetch_assoc();

$result = array();

//Use while instead of foreach
while ($value =  $resultb->fetch_assoc()) {
    $image = '<img width="50" height="40" class="rounded-circle" src="../' . $value['image'] . '; ?>">';

    $buttons = '<a href="product-update.php' . $value["id"] . '" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><a onclick="removeProduct(' . $value["id"] . ')" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>';

    // Add Keys For DataTable column
    $result[] = array(
        'description' => $value["description"],
        'price' => $value["price"],
        'image' => $image,
        'availability' => $value["availability"],
        'buttons' => $buttons,
    );
}

echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Comment: it has an error on line 18

$key is undefined.

after removing the $key, the output is only 1 row, the last row data on the database

output should be all data within the database

Comment: @LexCabrera i removed the `$key`. Try it again.

Comment: @LexCabrera This should  display all active status in your product. Check your product table if you only have 1 `active` row.

Comment: there's more than 1 "active" row here

Comment: Can you `var_dump($result);die();` after the `while` loop. Put it outside of `while` loop.

Comment: And also add `echo $resultb->num_rows;` before the while loop.

Comment: there's 24 result for active status

Comment: Can you please double check your `$result` inside of `while` loop. It should be `$result[]` instead of `$result`

Comment: all data is now fetchable. thank you.

but the problem about displaying the $result[] into the dataTable is still present

Comment: @LexCabrera I updated my answer. Please check. You need to add a `key` as  a column.

Comment: @LexCabrera If this answere your question. Don't forget to accept it as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: i'm still unable to display the data to the datatable. what do you mean when you said I should put a key on the $result[] ?

edit:
ive used the $value["id"] inside the $result[]

Comment: i;ve used your code, it's copying my desired data, but it's not displaying it on the dataTable

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Bluetree 's answer, the adding of keys for the dataTable was unnecessary.

The right approach is that the encoded arrays of data should be first inputted with a data string "data" inside the array first because we simply need to follow the format needed by the dataTable.

```
<?php
include_once('../../components/db.php');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE status='active'";
$query = $conn->query($sql);

while($data=$query->fetch_assoc()){
    $image = '<img width="50" height="40" class="rounded-circle" src="../' . $data['image'] . '">';

    $buttons = '<a href="product-update.php' . $data['id'] . '" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><a onclick="removeProduct(' . $data['id'] . ')" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>';

    // instead of just $result[], we need to use $result[data][] in order to use it for dataTable
    $result["data"][] = array(
        $data['names'],
        $data['description'],
        $data['price'],
        $image,
        $data['availability'],
        $buttons,
    );
}

echo json_encode($result);

// console.log output would be {"data":[["Blueberry Cheesecake"," This blueberry cheesecake starts with a buttery graham cracker crust, a creamy cheesecake center, and a tangy blueberry swirl.","80.00","","Available","<\/i><\/a><\/i><\/a>"],["Fruity Split","Dessert made with a split banana, ice cream, sauce, whipped cream, nuts, and a strawberry.","50.00","","Available","<\/i><\/a><\/i><\/a>"],["Pancake","Pancake topped with blueberry and strawberry.","80.00","","Available","<\/i><\/a><\/i><\/a>"],["Steak","Steak. . . . . in which I need to output
?>
```

The AJAX within the dataTable needs to have a URL and the data itself.
providing it with just:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "ajax": "data.json",
  }
} );
```

would be the shorthand way of encoding it like this:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "ajax": {
    "url": "data.json",
    "data": {
        "user_id": 451
    }
  }
} );
```

because the first sample format of ajax already have a url and data itself. the return value within the url is the data itself, and the url for the ajax is the url itself. thus, we need to have a "data" inside the returned value within the encoded result of array.